# Append a dataframe to an existing google worksheet with that has data without overwriting the data

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-colaboratory, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have an existing worksheet that has data in one column that I have populated from a data frame. I want to take a different data frame and populate the second column in the worksheet but struggling to understand how to do it. What ends up happening is that it overwrites the data in the first column.

My column in the worksheet currently looks like this

```
Ilastik
0.1111082937
0.1744560321
0.1370938026
0.1028610827
0.6465271181
0.1871931638
0.1105310022
0.2431738711
0.4100191368
0.4919283379
```

I want it to look like

```
Ilastik         Kmeans
0.1111082937    0.473713
0.1744560327    0.359408
0.1370938026    0.368002
0.1028610827    0.219979
```

Both data have come from different dataframes. I opened my worksheet using

```
worksheet_hemp_kmeans = sh.worksheet("Hemp Model Results")
```

And then tried adding the dataframe to it. hemp_kmeans_df2 is my dataframe that I want to add.

```
worksheet_hemp_kmeans.update([hemp_kmeans_df2.columns.values.tolist()] +hemp_kmeans_df2.values.tolist())
```

Comment: Now I noticed that your issue had been resolved. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this case, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. I deeply apologize for this. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again. I would like to study more. I really apologize for my very poor skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I managed to work it by doing

```
worksheet_hemp_kmeans.update("B1", [hemp_kmeans_df2.columns.values.tolist()] +hemp_kmeans_df2.values.tolist())
```